# Resharper: Search for variables of type long with int asignment

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, resharper

Is it possible to search for all variables/properties with type long that gets an int assigned to them?

Example: 

        `public static YieldRecord FromPalletDataRow(DataRow aDataRow, out long aYieldId)
        {
           aYieldId = aDataRow.GetValue<int>(POY.YieldId);

           YieldRecord yieldRecord = new YieldRecord();
           yieldRecord.OrderId = aDataRow.GetValue<long>(PO.OrderId);`

Here i parse as an int, the field is long. (In the database its bigint).
Some places `int.Parse` or `int.TryParse` might have been used.
Some places `GetNullableValue<int>`

I might first have parsed it to an local int variable then asigned that local int to a long.

I need to find everywhere i have assigned an integer to a long..

This is a very big project with 3 different solutions. But if there is no such tool in resharper i have to go trough it manualy or make some regexes.

Thank you. 
Tor Einar

Comment: This feels like a XY Problem - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem . **Why** do you want to do this?

Comment: I have used int in code but BigInt in database. I have changed it to long and want to make sure i haven't missed any.

Comment: Make sure you haven't missed any *what*? `long myLong = 4;` and `long myLong = 4L;` have *exactly the same effect*.

Comment: The value comes from a database with underlaying bigint type. Its fine until it blows up couse the db value is to big for an int.

Comment: I see your edit, but I'm still not clear what the problem is, unless you actually mean the other way round. Show us some code that actually blows up. Assigning an `int` value to `long` variable can't fail!